# how to store data to local device from server with titanium?

Tags: cookies, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I want to make a auto login when users used APP after first time.I tried to keep it in alloy.js and Ti.App.Properties.getString('login_token'),but they didn't work.

in my coffee:

```
result = JSON.parse this.responseText
console.info result.token  #"dsfdsfds2142fds3r32rf32e3dfefwedf"
Ti.App.Properties.setString "token",result.token
console.info Ti.App.Properties.getString "token"  # it's blank
```

Comment: Paste full code and let me know in detail what you need to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a built in way to do this so i just created a getter and setter method and put it in alloy.js.   Feels very hacky and dirty but it does work.

```
//retrieves the value of the token
// also checks if the token is valid and sets logged_in accordingly
function getToken(){
    var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'api.txt');
    var content = f.read();

    //if we can read this return it, otherwise return a blank value
    if (content){
      return content.text;  
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}

//persists and sets the value of token to the new value
function setToken(key){
    var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'api.txt');
    f.deleteFile();
    var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'api.txt');
    f.write(key);
    token = key;
}
```